# Software Center install hung in the middle, no network activity

Tags: command-line, software-center

I went to The Ubuntu Software screen, searched for ClamAV, found ClamTK and selected for install. The process shows about 50% done and hangs. I checked the system monitor Network History and there is no activity. It's been like this for 30+min. I think I would like to abort the install, remove associated files, and maybe find a better AV.
Under processes, I'm not sure which to end, nor how to clean this up. Of course, having about an hour's experience in Ubuntu makes this more of a challenge.

Comment: Just to let you know, ClamTK is just the GUI, ClamAV is the actual and great AV. This is a common issue with Ubuntu, it has nothing to do with ClamAV, you are likely to encounter this issue with other apps in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda changing the .deb default "open with" app from `Software Center` to `gdebi` usually makes installs much more reliable.

Comment: @heynnema: I took it to understand though that they wanted to install it from Software Center and hadn't already downloaded the `.deb` file from anywhere. Or at least there is no mention of that.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda you're correct. I have them downloading the clamtk .deb file later in my answer, and I wanted gdebi to install it, and I jumped the gun in my comment to you... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Install clamav and clamtk this way...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get purge clamav clamtk # remove partially installed apps
sudo apt-get update # update the software database
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk # install clamav and the GUI
```

To make future .deb file installs go easier and more reliable than the `Software Center`...

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi # this may already be installed
```

Then right-click on any .deb file (like the one you download in the next paragraph), and change the default "open with" app from `Software Center` to `gdebi`.

Then go to https://dave-theunsub.github.io/clamtk/ and download the newer version of clamtk (https://bitbucket.org/dave_theunsub/clamtk/downloads/clamtk_5.24-1_all.deb) and install it by double-clicking on it. Make sure to set the various preferences, folders to scan, recurse folders, and the "scheduler" scans for database updates, and auto scans.

Comment: I restarted and that seemed to clear the partial install. The command provided in the answer found no partially install apps.